# Python Syntax Error (except ValueError:)

Tags: python, syntax-error

I have a small code which is just for me to get more used to python and I have encountered a problem with try and except.

I am trying to get the code below to ask a question and receive an answer using raw_input. If you know what the syntax error in line 22 is? (except ValueError)
Thank you very much.

```
def start():
    print("Type start")
    prompt_sta()
def prompt_sta():
    prompt_0 = raw_input ("Enter command start")
    try:
        if prompt_0 == "start":
            prompt_sta()
        elif prompt_0 == "begin":
            print ("You must learn to follow commands")
            prompt_sta()
        elif promt_0 == "help":
            print ("Commands:")
            print ("Help")
            print ("start")
            print ("begin")
            prompt_sta()
        else:
            print ("Please enter a valid command.")
            prompt_sta()
            print ("Type start")
        **except ValueError:**
def outside_house():
    print("There is a strange man outside.")
```

Just in case the error that IDEL is showing has ** on both sides and if you know any better ways for doing what I am trying to do please tell me. Thanks

Comment: python 3 doesn't have `raw_input`....

Comment: So should I use input instead?

Comment: If you're using python 3, yes. If you're using python 2, you want `raw_input`.

Comment: I've rolled back your edit because otherwise your question disappears for later readers! If you want to mark your question as answered, you can accept an answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to provide a body for `except:` statements:

```
try:
    a = "something"
except ValueError:
    pass  # empty body
```

Comment: OK, but what is that doing?

Comment: `pass` is an empty statement, it does nothing. The point is that `except` expects a body in which it will handle the exception.

Comment: OK so nothing extra is after pass it is just empty or is there something I should include?

Comment: I don't understand your question I'm afraid. `# empty body` is just a comment. If you add `pass` after `except:` your syntax error should be resolved.

Comment: I feel really stupid, how do I run the code without instant crash?

Comment: I'm not I checked in IDEL and Notepad++ and it shows no errors.

Comment: It's blank, just black background no text.

Comment: Add `start()` to the end of the program so you actually call a function. Otherwise the file only contains definitions. It doesn't crash, it just doesn't do anything without that.

Comment: The title of the window is C:\Windows\py.exe

Comment: Yeah it worked, can't believe i forgot something so simple, thank you for the help